# EditCommandColumn Image not clickable

Tags: asp.net, datagrid

I have made an image as the Edit text button.
For some reason I can't click it. Am I missing something?
If I leave it as text it is fine.

```
<asp:EditCommandColumn EditText="<li class='fa fa-pencil-square-o' style='color:green;background-color:white;font-size:25px;'/>" CancelText ="Cancel" UpdateText="Update" ItemStyle-Width="60" />
```

UPDATE:

HTML Rendered

[image]

Comment: Could you share how that link is being rendered?

Comment: Like an image of what it looks like?

Comment: I mean the HTML generated

Comment: @hardkoded added screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently you can't encase the image in a `<li>`

I changed it to a `<span>` and it worked :)

```
 <asp:EditCommandColumn EditText="<span aria-hidden='true' class='fa fa-pencil-square-o' style='color:green;background-color:white;font-size:25px;'/>" CancelText ="Cancel" UpdateText="Update" ItemStyle-Width="60" />
```